# OCR scanned maps using Google Vision API

Tags: json, pdf, gis, ocr, google-cloud-vision

My ultimate goal is to read the land owner name, and record the location, from a series of Rural Maps. See [here](https://www.rmofmartin.com/map) for an example of the input. Right now my idea is to use the Google vision API to extract the text and then link the text back to the original grid coordinates on the map. I use the standard python code to extract this text from [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf). This leaves me with 2 questions:

1) I understand that the API outputs only JSON files. Does this JSON record the PDF coordinates of the extracted text?
2) Is there a way to convert this JSON into a simplified Searchable PDF of the original, where only the text is present?

As well, if anyone knows of any better ways to OCR this map and extract the string locations I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences with the Google OCR (using PHP as scripting language - but this should not make any difference since your question depends on the API and not on python) you can do this.

As you can see in the API documentation, each text block found by the OCR comes with the four points which describe the bounding box (rectangular):
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

In your example map the quality of the text is quite bad. That will give you a lot of wrong or missing OCR results.

To convert this text into a PDF you need to do your own coding since this task is very specific.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you. The actual maps I am using are high quality scans of physical maps I have in my possession; the web example was chosen just for copyright purposes, sorry for the confusion. As long as I can link the bounding box coordinates to the original map, I think I can skip the second step.